# Samba server becomes slow after a while

Tags: samba

I have a samba server (running on a pine64) talking (via router via eithernet) to an Android TV box. I also have a laptop on wifi.

Most of the time this setup works fine, but every now and then I get samba starting to crawl or stop altogether. This is on both the TV and the laptop. `htop` on the pine64 does not show any significant cpu load. A restart of `smbd` fixes the issue, albeit temporarily.

Can someone tell me how to debug this or what the issue might be? Any tuning resources might help too. If I don't get anything im close to considering a cronjob that reboots `smbd` daily.

Pine64 runs ubuntu, Android TV box is on 4.1.1 I think, and laptop is Windows 10 with Linux mint rosa VM.

Comment: Is not when reading and writing? pine64 does not have a SATA interface, USB 2, no? I would prefer a banana pi with a sata interface for that. You do not want to look at CPU load, but at interrupts/IO.